# Error in adding Pushe unity plugin to my android app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, pushe

When I want to add pushe unity plugin to my app I saw the following error.

Anybody know whats going wrong?

```
Failed to compile resources with the following parameters:  
-bootclasspath ".../UNITY/android-sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar" -d
"..\unity-sample-master\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8
"co\ronash\pushe\Manifest.java"
"co\ronash\pushe\R.java"
"com\google \android\gms\Manifest.java"
"com\google\android\gms\R.java"
"com\google\android\gms \base\Manifest.java"
"com\google\android\gms\base\R.java"
warning: [options] source value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

3 warnings
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your unity is using `java 1.6` for compiling your project.

According to my experience, unity 5 needs `java 1.8` or higher. This applies to most recent unity plugins which are built with recent versions of unity, including `Pushe plugin`.

So try changing the java version which your unity uses to `1.8` or above following below path:

```
Edit -> Preferences -> External tools
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well. I tried "changing the java version which unity uses to 1.8" as the previous answer suggested but couldn't find any option to do so in the External tools menu. I also tried figuring out how to append the "-Xlint:-options" parameter suggested in the error spew but couldn't find the right place to set this and it seemed like a hack to begin with.

The only solution I found was to downgrade from JDK 9 to [JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). You will also need to update the JDK path in Unity from Edit -> Preferences -> External tools.

My JDK path changed from:

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home

To:

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home